# Activity indicator in status bar always hidden

Tags: ios, swift, activity-indicator

I have searched many answers to this question but non of them was working. In my case, my project requires the "View controller-based status bar appearance" set to `NO`, so it looks like there is only one solution to do this. I added to my `AppDelegate`, in function `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, `application.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false`. Tried to do so in my main view controller in `viewDidLoad`, but both doesn't hide this indicator. Any ideas?

Comment: Which network framework are you using?

Comment: ATInternet, Alamofire, Reachability, guess no more 3rd party

Comment: I think is your network framework how enables the activity indicator in the status bar

Comment: Searched through whole project - none such a method in those frameworks, so nothing overrides my declaration in AppDelegate

Comment: The same behaviour in iOS 9, 10 & 11, so for sure not the iOS fault

Comment: can you post a chunk of code where you are using your network framework?

Comment: There is so many places where I use something based on networking frameworks that I cannot fully satisfy your wish. But certainly it looks like non of them unhide this indicator. Maybe some Cocoa Touch lib, but then Apple wouldn't create the `isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible`, because it would be senseless

Comment: Which networking framework are you using?

Comment: You have them listed above

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide the status bar try this in your view controller.

override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

Comment: I need the status bar. What I need more is to hide ONLY the activity indicator in it